# Agrupando dados por intervalos de horas no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Atualmente tenho a seguinte consulta no banco de dados SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 5 
CAST(CAST(CAST(CAST(E3TimeStamp as float)*24 as bigint) as float)/24 as datetime) as hora,
CAST(CAST(CAST(CAST(E3TimeStamp as float)*24 as bigint) as float)/24 as datetime)+0.04167 as hora_final,

AVG(TOTALIZADO_FIT300) as campo1,
AVG(TOTALIZADO_FIT100eFIT300) as campo2

FROM FATURAMENTO

GROUP BY CAST(CAST(CAST(CAST(E3TimeStamp as float)*24 as bigint) as float)/24 as datetime)
ORDER BY Hora ASC
```

Resultado da consulta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu problema é que com este agrupamento (GROUP BY), a consulta me retorna os valores de Hora em Hora, exemplo:

- Média dos valores entre 2019-02-01 00:00:00 á 2019-02-01 00:59:59

Preciso que, o agrupamento ocorra por exemplo entre o intervalo:

- Média dos valores entre 2019-02-01 00:00:00 á 2019-02-01 01:00:00

E assim por diante.

Complemento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode-se notar, pelo motivo de que o agrupamento não ocorre das 00:00:00 as 01:00:00 e sim das 00:00:00 ás 00:59:59, com isso, tenho discrepância de valores.

Comment: Você quer dizer que deseja que o limite superior de seu intervalo seja também considerado como o limite inferior do intervalo seguinte? Caso exista uma ocorrência exatamente neste instante ela não será considerada em duplicata? Você já pensou em truncar seu campo timestamp para hora e agregar por ele?

Comment: Exatamente. Pois da forma como estou fazendo agora esta ocorrendo problemas com os valores totais.

Esta aplicação salva dados a cada 1 segundo no banco de dados com o valor da produção da fábrica. 

Pensei em fazer isso, truncar o campo para hora. Vou fazer este teste e posto o resultado.

Comment: Como está declarada a coluna `E3TimeStamp`? Como ela armazena a data e hora? Achei muito estranha a conversão dela para datetime.

Comment: Adicionei conteúdo na descrição do problema. Fiz a junção conforme comentado acima. 

@JoséDiz este E3TimeStamp é um datetime e utilizo ele como Chave Primária também.

Comment: @Agnaldo: volto a insistir que se você considerar o limite superior de um intervalo sendo exatamente igual ao limite inferior do intervalo seguinte (e não estritamente menor que é o que me parece correto) e você tiver um evento exatamente neste instante você irá considerar o valor associado a este instante nos dois intervalos, o que não me parece logicamente consistente, mas é o que você vem descrevendo em seus comentários.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eis sugestão para retornar as médias por hora:

```
-- código #1 v3
SELECT (convert (char(13), E3TimeStamp, 121) + ':00') as hora, 
       avg (TOTALIZADO_FIT300) as campo1,
       avg (TOTALIZADO_FIT100eFIT300) as campo2
  from FATURAMENTO_2
  group by convert (char(13), E3TimeStamp, 121);
```

---

Se as linhas cujo valor de horário esteja hh:00:00 devem constar tanto da faixa atual quanto da faixa anterior, eis outra sugestão:

```
-- código #2
with agFAT as (
SELECT E3TimeStamp,
       dateadd (hour, datediff (hour, 0, E3TimeStamp), 0) as Hora,
       TOTALIZADO_FIT300, TOTALIZADO_FIT100eFIT300
  from FATURAMENTO
  -- where ...

union all

-- obtém linhas que são hh:00.00
SELECT dateadd (second, -1, E3TimeStamp), 
       dateadd (hour, datediff (hour, 0, dateadd (second, -1, E3TimeStamp)), 0),
       TOTALIZADO_FIT300, TOTALIZADO_FIT100eFIT300
  from FATURAMENTO
  where (datediff_big (second, 0, E3TimeStamp) % 3600) = 0
        -- and ...
)
SELECT Hora,
       avg (TOTALIZADO_FIT300) as campo1,
       avg (TOTALIZADO_FIT100eFIT300) as campo2
  from agFAT
  group by Hora;
```

Não testei; pode conter erro(s).

As linhas cujo valor de horário esteja hh:00:00 são duplicadas, mas com um segundo a menos. Isto faz com que elas também participem da faixa anterior.

Linhas com valor hh:00:00 são aquelas cujo valor convertido para segundos são valores múltiplos de 3.600.

Comment: Tentei implementar sua solução. Adicionei um print com o retorno que tive.
Porém, fazendo desta forma o agrupamento ocorreu das 00:00:00 às 00:59:59, quando o mesmo deveria de ser 00:00:00 às 01:00:00

Comment: Se a coluna E3Timestamp está declarada como datetime, então não é necessário aquela sequencia de CAST.

Comment: @AgnaldoJunior Acrescentei o código #2

Comment: Isso mesmo. Obrigado!